# is there any way to find the execution time of line by line in android?

Tags: android

What is the easiest to time execution in Android?

I have looked around a bit and I found TimingLogger on the Android SDK, and instructions here. It looks very convenient. But I can't get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest:

```
final long before = System.nanoTime();
measuredMethod();
final long delay = System.nanoTime() - before;
```

But I would recommend using [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) tool.

Comment: Traceview is part of DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor Server). Check this: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html and this: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can call

`long start = System.currentTimeMillis();` on your first line and

`long timeExecution = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;` on your last line

then you can print or use the timeExecution

Comment: How to use TimingLogger in android ???                    I dont want to use long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); after every statement.